My page keeps jumping when I expand my FAQ section
I am building an FAQ section. When I comment out the
.hide-display {
  display: none;
}

, I see that my page jumps up to the top. How do I make it so that the section only expands downwards and doesn't jump to the top of the page?


<body>
    <main>
      <section>
        <h6>
          <span class="question">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur? </span
          >
        </h6>
        <p class="text">
        Morbi nisi orci, dignissim vel sagittis vel, dignissim non orci. Ut sit amet velit eget magna vehicula venenatis.
        </p>
      </section>

      <section>
        <h6>
          <span class="question"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit?</span>
        </h6>
        <p class="text hide-display">
          Morbi nisi orci, dignissim vel sagittis vel, dignissim non orci. Ut sit amet velit eget magna vehicula venenatis.
        </p>
      </section>
    <main>
      <body>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 65vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

main {
  width: 40%;
}

.hide-display {
  display: none;
}


Your MAIN element is being vertically centered in the body (align-items:center on the BODY which is a flex-box).  It's not jumping to the top, it's just that a taller box that is still centered reaches further up the page.

@Carsen How do I fix it?

It's not jumping to top in my case. Share codepen or something with issue you facing.

Are you saying that initially you want it vertically centered but after that the top is to remain in the same place and the element expand downwards?

What do you want it to look like when the unexpanded element is taller than the viewport?

@James  The "fix" is to use a different method to lay out the page.  There are thousands of ways.  It's not clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish so I can't speak to the best one (that's why this is a comment and not an answer).  Brett Donald's answer below will work as long as you don't care that MAIN is vertically centered on page load.

@AHaworth I want the top of the element to remain in the same place regardless if it is expanded or not.

Don’t use flexbox to style your body. Just set a suitable top margin.


body {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background: lavender;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

main {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 0.5em 2em 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

details {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

summary {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
<main>

  <h2>FAQs</h2>
  
  <details>
    <summary>Question 1</summary>
    Morbi nisi orci, dignissim vel sagittis vel, dignissim non orci. Ut sit amet velit eget magna vehicula venenatis.
  </details>  
  
  <details>
    <summary>Question 2</summary>
    Morbi nisi orci, dignissim vel sagittis vel, dignissim non orci. Ut sit amet velit eget magna vehicula venenatis.
  </details>

<main>



